# Usar setSupportActionBar no Fragmento

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-fragment

Tenho um app que usa o `NavigationDrawer`, preciso alterar o nome do `toolbar` para cada fragmento.

O meu `MainActivity` extende do `AppCompatActivity` então eu consigo alterar o nome do fragmento usando:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("Nome Fragmento");
```

Só que no meu fragmento principal tenho botões que também chama `fragmentos`, e preciso que o nome deles seja alterado, mas não consigo usar o `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` vi em algum lugar o pessoal usando `((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` mas também não consigo, ele abre a aplicação e quando clico no botão o app fecha e da o seguinte erro no Logcat:

```
05-03 15:16:30.305 14847-14847/com.example.expres E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.expres.fragmentos.principal$1.onClick(principal.java:95)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4476)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18795)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Preciso muito de ajuda.

Comment: Não entendo muito de Android Studio, mas `NullPointerException` aparece quando se tenta acessar algum campo/método nulo. Se o erro ocorre nesta linha `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`, provavelmente o toolbar está nulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem a lógica de negócio, normalmente aconselharia a usar um toolbar central na activity e usar o fragment apenas para o conteúdo, mas seguindo sua lógica, seria assim:

```
v = inflater.inflate (R.layout.layout, container, false);

    Toolbar toolbar = v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar (toolbar);
    if(((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar () != null) {
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); //Mostrar o botão
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setTitle ("TITULO");
    }
```

E se você quiser usar os eventos neste mesmo contexto:

```
toolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Funcionou @Rodrigo só que, o botão queria que ele voltasse para o fragmento principal, mas ele abre o menu.